# Getting a different output

Tags: java, arrays

I'm getting a different output.The output I want is-
Quizzes: 66%
Labs: 88%
Lab attendance: 81%
Midterms: 91%
Final: Not applicable
Overall Average: 85%.
But I'm getting

output:

```
[I@176c74b
[I@116471f
[I@1975b59
[I@lee3914
```

My method normalize is suppose to get the percentage then goes to the average method. I call this method for quizArray,labArray,attendance, midterms to try to get the grades for each of them.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FindGrade {
    public static final int NUM_SCORE_TYPES = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = null;
        int[] quizArray = null;
        int[] labArray = null;
        int[] attendance = null;
        int[] midterms = null;
        int quizgrade = 0;
        int labgrade = 0;
        int attendance_1 = 0;
        int midterms_1 = 0;
        String name;


        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // each iteration is for single exam type (ie: Quizzes is the 1st one)
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SCORE_TYPES; i++) {

            name = scan.next();
            int numScores = scan.nextInt();
            int maxGrade = scan.nextInt();

            if (name.equals("Quizzes")) {
                quizArray = new int[numScores];
                readScores(quizArray, numScores, scan);


            } else if (name.equals("Labs")) {
                labArray = new int[numScores];
                readScores(labArray, numScores, scan);

            } else if (name.equals("Lab_attendance")) {
                attendance = new int[numScores];
                readScores(attendance, numScores, scan);

            } else if (name.equals("Midterms")) {
                midterms = new int[numScores];
                readScores(midterms, numScores, scan);

            }

        }

    }


    public static void readScores(int[] scoreArray, int numScores, Scanner scan) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numScores; i++) {
            scoreArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        average(scoreArray, numScores);
    }

    public static int normalize(int[] scoreArray, int maxGrade) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
            total += scoreArray[i];
        }
        int percent = Math.round(total * 100 / maxGrade);
        return percent;
    }

    public static double average(double[] scoreArray, int numScores) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
            sum += scoreArray[i];
        }
        double average = sum / numScores;

        return average;


    }
```

input file:

```
Quizzes 8 10
5 8 9 10 4 0 10 7
Labs 6  100
95  90  100  87  63  92
Lab_attendance  16  1
1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1
Midterms  2  100
87  94
Final  0  100
```

Comment: You are missing one `}` at end in source code.

Comment: where is you output? And where do you call the `normalize` and `average` method?

Comment: My output is at the top.

Comment: I call the average method in readScores but I'm not sure where to call the normalize method

Answer (score 1):

Each *object* has [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method, its default will display the *class name representation*, then adding `@` and then the *hashcode*. I assume that you're printing `System.out.println(someArray)`.

You should use [`Arrays#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29) (Below is the implementation of it so you can better understand it):

```
3860     public static String toString(int[] a) { {
3861        if (a == null)
3862            return "null";
3863        int iMax = a.length - 1;
3864        if (iMax == -1)
3865            return "[]";
3866
3867        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
3868        b.append('[');
3869        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
3870            b.append(a[i]);
3871            if (i == iMax)
3872                return b.append(']').toString();
3873            b.append(", ");
3874        }
3875    }
```

Comment: This gives me the entire array. I'm trying to get the percentage: 66%